# Possible way to define $H_0^1(\Omega)$ Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\Bbb R^d$: consider the following function spaces

- $H_0^1(\Omega)$, i.e. the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $H^1(\Omega)$
- $H_*(\Omega)$, i.e. the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $H^1(\Bbb R^d)$.
- $H_{\Omega}(\Omega)=\{u\in H^1(\Bbb R^d):\ u= 0  \text{ a.e on } \Omega^c\}$.

**Question**: does the above spaces coincide? If not when are they equal?

Comment: The first two should be equivalent, as the $H^1(\Omega)$ norm and $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ norm of $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ functions are the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first two are equivalent, as the $H^1(\Omega)$ norm and $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ norm coincide for $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ functions.

The third is in general different:

If you let $d = 1$ and $\Omega = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$,
you see that $H_{\Omega}(\Omega) = H^1(\mathbb{R}) \supsetneq H^1_0(\Omega)$. You can create similar examples in higher dimensions (by omitting a hyperplane instead of a point). On the other hand, if $\Omega$ is a Sobolev extension domain (see e.g. Leoni's *First Course in Sobolev Spaces*) then $u\in H^1_0(\Omega) \iff$ extending $u$ by zero to the exterior gives an $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ function. And in that case, the third is equivalent to the first two.

Comment: Your next question would be: when is $\Omega$ a Sobolev extension domain? It is sufficient that $\Omega$ has Lipschitz boundary. But I don't think there is a known (useful) characterization result.

Comment: please how do you show that the inclusion is strict?

Comment: @GuyFsone: by Morrey's inequality every element in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is almost everywhere equal to a continuous function that vanishes at $0$. So a smooth bump function that does not vanish at $0$ is an element of $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ but not in $H^1_0(\Omega)$.